# Recursive CTE compatible in both SQL Server and PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a recursive CTE that works fine in SQL Server, I am trying to adapt the query to make it work in PostgreSQL, the requirement is that the same query works well in both SQL Server and PostgreSQL.

How can I convert this query [sql-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7C54UpBWFNQsSC1jCx7SV6/1) to a recursive query that will work on both databases?

The depth of hierarchy is variable, could be 1, 2, 3, or 50. I have tried doing a recursive query but my knowledge of SQL is very limited.

Schema SQL

```
create table IdentityTable (id int, name varchar(255));
insert into IdentityTable values (1, 'Lionel');
insert into IdentityTable values (2, 'Head Office User');
insert into IdentityTable values (3, 'Snapshot Access');
insert into IdentityTable values (4, 'Employee Administrator');
insert into IdentityTable values (5, 'Event Type Administrator');

create table IdentityUserGroupAsmt (id int, identityTable int, userGroup int);
insert into IdentityUserGroupAsmt values (1, 1, 2);
insert into IdentityUserGroupAsmt values (2, 2, 3);
insert into IdentityUserGroupAsmt values (3, 3, 4);
insert into IdentityUserGroupAsmt values (4, 4, 5);
```

Query SQL

```
with 
    cte as (    
        select it.name, it.id, iuga.userGroup from IdentityTable it
            join IdentityUserGroupAsmt iuga
                on it.id = iuga.identityTable
        where it.name = 'Lionel'
        
    union all

        select it.name, it.id, iuga.userGroup from IdentityUserGroupAsmt iuga
            join cte cte
                on cte.userGroup = iuga.identityTable
            join IdentityTable it
                on iuga.userGroup = it.id
    )

select * from cte
```

Comment: The last part of your query is wrong. `select * from cte group by name, id, userGroup` You need to use include those in `GROUP BY` in the `SELECT` and use aggregate function.  As for same query in `PostgresSQL` you need to add the keyword `RECURSIVE` after `WITH`. [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @DaleK, I have updated the question, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can't meet the requirement that:

> the same query works well in both SQL Server and PostgreSQL.

In SQL Server you need to use regular CTE, in PostgreSQL you need to use CTE with special syntax `WITH RECURSIVE`.
Your application will have to detect the database engine and adjust the syntax accordingly.

Another option would be to build a dedicated Stored Procedure for each database.

Comment: So there is no plain SQL equivalent that could work on both? I am not saying to stick with CTE

Comment: Nope, there is not.